# Is there a way to save the boot log in of the simics launch demo?

Tags: c, bios, edk2, simics

Is there a way to save the boot log in of the simics launch demo?
I build my own testbios and it works but I want to see the bootprocess log.

While I run the Launch demo I can see this one on serial console but I want to save it on a .txt

Answer (score 0):

Run the `help` command on the console you want to capture from to find the possible commands and features you can use for this. For example, when using the FirstSteps target:

```
help board.serconsole.con
```

Best regards

Simon

#IAmIntel